# Do a GET request with query parameters

Tags: http, go, get

I'm trying to do a request like this:

```
http://example.com/hello?name=username
```

But in the Docs I can't find a way to pass the payload parameter. (http.Get() only receives the url)

How can I do this request?

Comment: That is the url. `http.Get("http://example.com/hello?name=username")`

Comment: yes but is there any way to do this passing the payload like in python requests lib?

Comment: You can use [`url.Values`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values) to encode the parameters if you need.

Comment: what do you mean by payload? The query parameter? That's part of the url. You can build a url with the [url package](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/), or [fmt.Sprintf](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf). Usually "payload" refers to a request body, which GET doesn't really use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way it to simply add it to the URL:

```
  http.Get("http://example.com/hello?name=username")
```

The way I prefer to do it is to use `url.Values` to build the query string:

```
v := url.Values{}
v.Set("name", "username")
url := fmt.Sprintf("http://example.com/hello?%s", v.Encode())
http.Get(url)
```